What do we know about Christian, and especially Evangelicals voters, participation rates in US elections?
In a recent Trump-related question about Christians "not having to vote again in four years", several people made the point that Christians don't vote all that much, so it is reasonable for Trump to appeal to them to vote at least this once.

Trump says that Christians have a lot of voting power, but it's under-utilized because they don't turn out to vote.

Is this true, about Christian and esp. Evangelicals having low participation rates? We know there are strong participation rate correlations wrt age and income for example.
This Q is not concerned with whom they voted for (I've asked that about Evangelicals before - Trump @ 75%-ish in 2020, 80%-ish in 2016).
Nor is it particularly concerned about Trump specifics.  If Trump exhorts a group that votes 3/4 for him to go out and vote, that's just good politicking.  If Trump tells a group that doesn't vote much to go out and vote, also good politicking.  If Trump knows they actually are diligent voters but plays a bit of reverse psychology:  "look, I know you don't usually vote, but can you do it this once?" to really get as much of them off their couch as possible, that's also good politicking.  If Trump wants to instill a sense of urgency by giving them the sense their group is under-represented due to a real or imaginary lack of turnout... good politicking.
Only, are statements like Christians have a lot of voting power, but it's under-utilized because they don't turn out to vote. accurate or not?  Do Evangelicals or Christians actually vote less than the average American *, regardless of whom they vote for and whether or not they are being courted in a battleground state?
The Hill reports that Trump also claimed this on Fox News when asked about not needing to vote later:

“Christians do not vote well. They vote in very small percentages. Why? I don’t know. Maybe they’re disappointed in things that are happening,” Trump said. “I say, ‘You don’t vote. I’m saying go out, you must vote.’ But I said to the Christians in the room, thousands of them. I said, ‘Typically, Christians do not vote.’


“’Don’t worry about the future,’” he continued. “’You have to vote on Nov. 5. After that, you don’t have to worry about voting anymore. I don’t care, because we’re going to fix it. The country will be fixed … We won’t even need your vote anymore because, frankly, we will have such love.’”

p.s. FWIW, Trump's rally was The Believers' Summit which, with worship being led by Matt Brock and Kim Walker Smith do seem Evangelical-themed, though I welcome a correction if I got that wrong.
* this is where the distinction matters somewhat because the "average" American is Christian, though not necessarily Evangelical.

You seem to use Christians and Evangelicals somewhat interchangeably. The vast majority of Americans self-identifies as Christian, with hugely varying degrees of how religious they are. I think Evangelicals is a reasonably well defined group in the US, so maybe focus on that?

I don't use them interchangeably, but I am interested primarily in the Evangelicals.  A "vast majority of Americans are Christians" may be an overstatement.  Even in Georgia 18% of people are now non-denominational which puts them above the 2nd group - regular Protestants:  https://www.pewresearch.org/religious-landscape-study/database/state/georgia/  Florida, where Trump spoke 24% are non-religious https://www.pewresearch.org/religious-landscape-study/database/state/florida/  and the original Q got answers in terms of "Christians" and "Evangelicals".

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Evangelical isn a cross-denominational category, and non-denominational white Christians are predominantly Evangelicals, just rebranded.

To me Christian is the umbrella term that includes Evangelicals, Protestants, Catholics, etc. So this is everyone who is not Atheist, Muslim, Jewish or some other religion. I'm pretty sure that accounts for considerably more than half the US population.

@quarague does it matter that much to the Q?  No, it doesn't.  I roughly know the data but it has limited relevance to the Q as asked and consider that, while this retreat was Evangelical, Trump used the term Christian.  So a focus on either works.  This is a question about voter participation, not doctrinal nuances, even if Evangelicals, however they are identified, seem to be specifically counted as a distinct "denomination", whatever that means (as opposed to "regular Protestants").

TBH, I'm not sure why you expect this be something other than another Trump 'hyperbole' (i.e. falsehood). Aside, after the fiasco with the Black journalists interview yesterday [or so], maximizing turnout from his hardcore base is probably all that he has left, at this point.

The simple answer is that the religious vote at higher rates than religiously unaffiliated people.  This is described in the Washington Post (avoiding paywall).

For instance, in the 2012 election, the unaffiliated made up 18 percent of registered voters in preelection polls but only 12 percent of the people who actually voted, as measured in post-election exit polls. Some of this difference may be due to the different ways the two polls ask religious-affiliation questions, but Pew's researchers say that the underperformance of the non-religious is a very real phenomenon.

The complication with this sort of question is what is actually being measured here.  Religious affiliation is strongly correlated with many factors which are themselves correlated with voter turnout.  The complication of correlation between religious affiliation and demographic factors (not voter turnout) is discussed in this document which includes this diagram which I think illustrates the problem.  By controlling for these features, for example age which is a perfectly valid thing to do if you are asking the "right" question, could have a large influence on the effect one determines.

Radar chart showing correlation between religious affiliations and demographic features
Some confirmation of the effect comes from the UK, where this was measured last year:

If there were a UK General Election tomorrow, how likely is it that you would vote?

I'm not sure I understand what the last [UK] chart is supposed to show, in relation to the question.
